# Why my event on export bootstrap-tables is not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to make a function when the export start event happens, but I'm not able to catch this event. I'm trying `alert()` when `on export-started.bs.table`. Just doesn't work, so what is the event when I try export my table?

(I couldn't make an example of export in this code too, can someone help me put the button that downloads the file in excel?)

```js
let arrData = [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Item 0',
        'price': '$0'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Item 1',
        'price': '$1'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Item 2',
        'price': '$2'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Item 3',
        'price': '$3'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Item 4',
        'price': '$4'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': 'Item 5',
        'price': '$5'
      }
    ]

$('#merged').bootstrapTable({
    data: arrData,
    exportTypes: ['csv','json','excel','doc','txt','sql','xml'],
    exportDataType: 'all',
    columns: [{
                title: "id",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "id"
            },{
                title: "name",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "name"
            },{
                title: "price",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "price"
            }]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.0/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table class="table" id="merged">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. You must enter the event in the table configuration.

```
onExportStarted: function (arg1, arg2) { alert('hi'); },
```

```js
let arrData = [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Item 0',
        'price': '$0'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Item 1',
        'price': '$1'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Item 2',
        'price': '$2'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Item 3',
        'price': '$3'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Item 4',
        'price': '$4'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': 'Item 5',
        'price': '$5'
      }
    ]

$('#merged').bootstrapTable({
    data: arrData,
    exportTypes: ['csv','json','excel','doc','txt','sql','xml'],
    exportDataType: 'all',
    showExport: true,
    onExportStarted: function (arg1, arg2) { alert('hi'); },
    columns: [{
                title: "id",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "id"
            },{
                title: "name",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "name"
            },{
                title: "price",
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                field: "price"
            }]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.0/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table class="table" id="merged">
  </table>
</div>
```